# webservice authentication via SSL

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, ssl

I have different websites calling my webservice (C#) that has SSL. How can I check in my webserver if the calling site has SSL and if it does return data otherwise error message.

Comment: A client that wants to communicate with your SSL enabled server(`https`) **must have** SSL support and start the comm on port 443. I don't think you should worry about it or have to do anything.

Comment: ok, thx for your reply, how would I configure my webserver to use only SSL enabled because currently http and https can access it! Thx!

Comment: I am not an IIS expert(assuming you use it even you haven't mentioned about your server). It seems to be a good SO question, **if not asked yet**. `How would I configure my webserver to use only SSL`

Comment: Is this an ASMX web service, or WCF?

Comment: Just to clarify the question. Do you want to check the the websites calling your WS are themselves served over HTTPS or just that they're capable of making HTTPS connections to your WS? (What do you mean by "check in my webserver if the calling site **has SSL**"?)

Comment: Hi Bruno, sorry I am new to all of this and not sure what I am asking makes sense, but this is what I thought, websites can call my ws over https but in order to communicate with my methods they need to have SSL on there side otherwise don't allow them to interact with my methods. Thx

Comment: The only thing you are going to be able to enforce is that the communication to your server is SSL. You have no way of knowing about anything that happens before they attempt to connect to you, nor do you have any control of how they use any of the information you provide. If you're concerned about this, it sounds like a contractual issue between you and all your potential clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force the connection to only be SSL by configuring the following on your website in IIS:

In IIS6, go to Directory Security -> "Edit" under Secure communications and check "Require secure channel (SSL)"

In IIS7, in the features view, go to SSL Settings, click "Force SSL"